# How can i add to hash maps that have already been created elsewhere?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an Array of Hashmaps and i need to compare data from that with another Array so i can add more data to the Hashmap. However when i add to the hashmap in the comparison function it doesnt seem to stick. Here's my code:

```
private void meshData(){
        for(Map<String,String> map: dataMap){
            for(List<String> arrayLine: statusArray){
                if(map.get("shortName").equals(arrayLine.get(0))){
                    map.put("ActiveVlan", arrayLine.get(3));
                    System.out.println(map.get("shortName"));
                    //System.out.println("match");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I compare a `List<Map<String,String>>` (dataMap) to a `List<List<String>` (statusArray) which have been already been filled with data. When my names match up (in the if statement) i need to add another data cell held in statusArray. When i print this out there is no "ActiveVlan" in the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

This Line

```
map.put("ActiveVlan", arrayLine.get(3));
```

Means you are associating arrayLine.get(3) with the key ActiveVlan. Your map is a 1 to 1 mapping of String key to String value. Try adding

```
System.out.println(map.get("ActiveVlan");
```

To see what I mean. You likely want to form a new data structure, like a class that holds all the values you need, then form a map with that object as the value. Something like

```
Map<String, MyObject>
```